# Как считывать данные, когда iphone заблокирован?

Tags: xcode, iphone, swift4

Возможно ли считывание данные с iphone, когда устройство заблокировано? Есть приложение, записывающие данные, когда оно открыто или хотя бы смартфон разблокирован, а нужно записывать их так и при ходьбе

Comment: нада спарить / сконнектить bluetooth, и потом можно читать/писать, только если ваша программа на айфоне - нужно зделать чтобы она не заснула

Comment: С чем соединить? он считывает показатели с самого смартфона, как сделать так, что бы оно работало фоном?

Comment: ну так что, вопрос по человечески нельзя изложить?? Для iOS смотрите выполнение приложений в фоне - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Какие именно данные нужно? Геолокацию при ходьбе?

Comment: Акселеро́метр, для считывания шагов @VAndrJ

Comment: Так берите данные из healthkit, телефон сам их посчитает.